# Best way to repair the crawl space vent

Tags: vent, crawlspace, stucco

So I had a few questions as far as stucco vents go. Here is an image of what we are talking about:

[image: Stucco vent with hole]

What would be the best way to repair this hole? Just some wire mesh over it?

Some follow on questions

1. How did they mount this wire mesh to the stucco? My best guess is that they stapled it before the applied the 3 coats of stucco and it is semi embedded.
2. Is it recommended to paint over the mesh? Why was this done?

From this second picture on the bottom the mesh has started to come up. I'm semi confused at how this can be. Is the mesh attached to some type of aluminum frame that was originally embedded into the stucco and then the mesh started to come out from the frame?

[image: Another stucco vent]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What would be the best way to repair this hole?

The best fix applies to both of these vents, they should be replaced.

> How did they mount this wire mesh to the stucco?

It's likely stapled to the back of the stucco face, and there may be thin wood applied behind the mesh to help reinforce it and make it look embedded and not just tacked-on.

> My best guess is that they stapled it before the applied the 3 coats of stucco and it is semi embedded.

Exactly.

> Is it recommended to paint over the mesh? Why was this done?

Either the stucco or paint was probably applied by sprayer. It's extremely time-consuming to evenly paint a house exterior, and sprayers are much faster.

For your fix, replace the mesh the same way it was originally installed (you can check from inside the crawlspace, you'll have to get in there anyway to staple your new mesh) and then paint over it if you want it to match, or just the stucco frame around the new mesh.

Comment: Replacing the entire vent/mesh seems like a lot of work. My guess is you'd chisel around the mesh to get to the staples/nails that are holding the mesh in place, pry the mesh out, install a new one, then apply mortar around it again?

Comment: I tack it in place also very common galvanized construction fabric 1/4” is what that looks like to me.  I have several different size rolls 1/4” through 1/2” , I would also remove it for the best looking repair.

Comment: @JeffT I doubt you'd have to chisel through much, it's probably just a matter of prying the existing staples and thin wood frame off (from inside). Pry bar and/or catspaw + hammer would make short work of it.

Comment: If the mesh was stapled to the _outside_ of the wall then covered with stucco, there may be no internal framing. Just use diagonal cutters, tin snips and/or heavy duty scissors to cut out the mesh. Once it's gone, put some wire mesh over small wooden frames and apply to the inside of the wall. Screws will make it easy to remove if/when they need to be repaired again in the future.

Answer (score -1):

I think this product will work for you.

Tjernlund 950-8303 UnderAire Steel Crawl Space Vent, Morning Star Pattern, 18" x 10" Screen (Vent Screen Only) [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00BL7DSZA/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_glt_fabc_1AA5MRQK8MS6TDQ5NS0P](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BL7DSZA)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You should improve this answer because as it stands it is being flagged as low quality and is in danger of being deleted. Answers that are mostly just links to other web sites are also discouraged here due to the fact that the external web site may very well change. I would suggest as a minimum to post a picture and try to explain in your own words why you think this will work. If you capture a picture from another web site you should also add an attribution link in your answer.  This link is OK because if it goes stale your answer still remains here.